# Non-breaking vertical space between a table and a block of text

Tags: tables, vspace, tabularray

I have a very specific requirement to put a framed block of text at the bottom of the last page *but* never to be alone on a separate page. Currently I use a `\vspace*{\fill}` followed by a one-cell table. The first part of the requirement is nicely fullfilled, but not the second part (otherwise I wouldn't be asking). Currently I'm facing the issue between two `tabularray` tables, but a generic solution that also works with paragraphs would be nice.

TL;DR: What I would need is the vertical equivalent of a non-breaking space, I guess.

For context I'm using xetex and the MiKTeX distribution.

This simplified reproducer shows the second table jumping alone on the next page instead of taking the last three lines of the table with it:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{
    column{1} = {l},
}
odio\\
ut\\
enim\\
blandit\\
volutpat\\
maecenas\\
volutpat\\
blandit\\
aliquam\\
etiam\\
erat\\
velit\\
scelerisque\\
in\\
dictum\\
non\\
consectetur\\
a\\
erat\\
nam\\
at\\
lectus\\
urna\\
duis\\
convallis\\
convallis\\
tellus\\
id\\
interdum\\*
velit\\*
laoreet\\*
\end{longtblr}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{longtblr}{
    column{1} = {l}
}
Lorem ipsum \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible solution, the following example splits out the last three rows as a new table and checks if a newpage is needed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b6paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrOuter[longtblr]{footsep=0pt}
\SetTblrOuter[longtblr]{postsep=0pt}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand\MyLastRows[2]{%
  \savebox\mybox{\vbox{#1\par#2}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox\relax>\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
    \newpage
  \else
    \vspace{-0.4pt}%
  \fi
  \noindent#1\par\vfill\noindent#2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{colspec={X},hlines}
  odio\\
  ut\\
  enim\\
  blandit\\
  volutpat\\
  maecenas\\
  volutpat\\
  blandit\\
  aliquam\\
  etiam\\
  erat\\
  velit\\
  scelerisque\\
  in\\
  dictum\\
  non\\
  consectetur\\
  a\\
%  erat\\
%  nam\\
%  at\\
%  lectus\\
%  urna\\
%  duis\\
%  convallis\\
%  convallis\\
%  tellus\\
%  id\\
\end{longtblr}

\MyLastRows{%
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={X},hlines}
    interdum\\
    velit\\
    laoreet\\
  \end{tblr}
}{%
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={X},hlines}
    Lorem ipsum\\
  \end{tblr}
}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, it works very well, thanks! I had to adjust a bit the negative \vspace and for some reasons the tables were not perfectly aligned, I had to add a very small \hspace to have them aligned. What is the intention behind the \noindent before part #1 and #2 and the \par between them?

Comment: @jjolidon \noindent: remove \parindent; \par: end the paragraph.

Comment: After more trials I've found that tblr and longtblr have slightly different centering, hence the hspace. I could remove it after I switched to use longtblr for both tables.
I've also found that if you set presep=0pt for the second table and postsep=0pt for the first, in addition to footsep=0pt and headsep=0pt, the only required vspace between the tables is the width of the border (by default 0.4pt).